# How to make a centaur society and cities believable?

Tags: architecture, centaur

I'm doing quite a lot of worldbuilding these days, and as of right now, I want to make a centaur themed civilisation ; rather than having the classical centaurs living in the forest kind of centaurs, I want them to fully embrace civilization in a grandiose roman-style, mixed with elements of early medieval, celtic and even a bit of nordic vibes.

What would their cities should look like to be believable ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Well, they would wear clothes, togas specifically ; they wouldnt be butt-naked if that's the question.
One thing to consider is that these centaurs are quite bonded to magic and some are powerful enough to terraform locations. also, the land they inhabits are mainly plains, forests and a few hills, and it is a very big location, bigger than all of western europe, if those details can help with any suggestions :)

Comment: We have a whole tag about centaurs. [Have a look at these](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/centaur?tab=Votes) for inspiration. They should prompt more precise questions than "Hey what's up with centaur cities?" which should be closed as you have no specific problem to be solved.

Comment: I'm VTC because you're soliciting opinions rather than asking a specific question to which it is possible to give a correct answer. Stackexchange is intended for Q&A rather than discussion. FWIW I'd say centaurs are unsuited to forests, if they're the horsey kind. Horses like steppe and prairie and similar; room to run.

Comment: But I have a specific question, and that is : what would a centaur city look like ? I dont see how its not specific ; or did I missed something ?

Comment: @woolsei its still pretty wide open: you're assuming they want/need cities, not stating why, not stating where the city is, how big it might be, what the tech level is... the list goes on. You then end up in a situation where you can have half a dozen wildly different answers that are all in some sense correct but have no particular benefit over each other, which starts to fall afoul of the "matter of opinion" rules.

Comment: @woolsei honestly, I'm not sure how you'd turn this into a great WB.SE question, but consider: my centaurs live in environment X with tech level Y and a social structure like Z. They eat A, B and C, worship D, and trade E with their neighbours using F for transport. Maybe that's a bit _over_ constrained and you'd have almost answered it yourself, but if you _could_ ask a question of that form I feel you'd get some good answers from it.

Comment: @StarfishPrime why they want them surely falls under character motives & decisions so it's absence is not really relevant as a close reason for this question, would be of course if that was the question but it's not, so we should simply accept that in the OPs world they do & move on unless we want to do a frame challenge answer surely? // question is a bit broad yes as it covers everything like what would chairs look like along with a reasonably endless smorgasbord of other individual elements each of which under strict interpretation of site rules might require an individual question.

Comment: @Pelinore what a weird thing to say. If the people have no motivations compatible with city building and living, then there's clearly no reason for them to build or live in cities. Human motivations for living in cities are pretty important things, and have had a huge impact on human history.

Comment: @StarfishPrime might seem that way but them's still the rules, character motivations aren't something a question can ask about because that would be opinion based, I didn't make them (the rules)  i'm just repeating them  which makes someone who knows those rules criticizing a question for not including something irrelevant to answers as a result also weird 

Comment: @Pelinore no, you're trying to extrapolate an existing rule to a ridiculous extent. "_My creation needs oxygen to breathe_" -> oh no, they're motivated to breathe? Welp, gotta VTC, them's the rules.

Comment: @StarfishPrime  need is one thing, want is another, a physical need for oxygen is not a character choice, while a lifestyle choice like living in a city or not very definitely is, a poor choice on your part of an example of what you mean there perhaps? 

Comment: @Pelinore sounds like you're motivated to argue with me, and I'm afraid that's against the rules.

Comment: @StarfishPrime not at all, I agree this question is too broad, merely pointing out, correctly in my opinion, that particular element of your complaint is somewhat irrelevant and also invalid, you probably just got carried away with your speech, no shame in that, happens to the best of us, which I'm not  character motives are the purview of the writer ergo off limits for questions and by the same token not really a valid argument ('I don't agree with your characters choices') for saying a question is bad & should be closed.

Comment: I edited the question to make it more specific only to the architecture. Is it better ?

Answer (score 1):

**WIDE**

The buildings are larger than human buildings with wider doors. They are all single-story since centaurs are so heavy. The roofs are thatched because centaurs are too big and clumsy to carry heavy stuff up on a high scaffold.

(Or maybe they pay some other species to make the roof?)

This leads to a more sprawling city than a human city. There might be a few hundred metres between buildings rather than a few dozen for human cities. Centaurs don't mind this since they trot much faster than humans.

(Humans might not even refer to the place as a "city")

Inside the buildings, the floors are stone or dirt. Centaur feet will tear up any wooden or carpeted floor. Doubly so if they wear metal horseshoes.

The roads are wider than human roads. This is because Centaurs are bigger than humans so they need bigger roads.

There is no such thing as a "path" or a "road". The main vehicle is a centaur pulling a cart. These go right beside the "pedestrians" who have no cart.

Most of the carts are full of hay being pulled into the city in the morning, and carts of dung being pulled out in the evening. Or maybe everyone just wears a diaper.

[image]